# Particles disappear from starting spot after stop emitting

Tags: unity-game-engine, particles

I'm having trouble with particle system in Unity, where somke trail of rocket disappears from the starting spot instead of smoothly fading during lifetime. Below you can see animation that shows the problem.

[image]

Here's my particle configuration (I've skipped shape and renderer):

[image]

When rocket hits the ground I do the following:

```
_particleSystem.Stop();
Destroy(gameObject, 3.5f);
Destroy(projectilePrefab);
```

where:

- `gameObject` refers to container of both, particle system and rocket
  sprite,
- `_particleSystem` is component of children GameObject,
- `projectilePrefab` is the rocket sprite.

I've also tried changing emission rate multipliers and start lifetime, with no success.
So I'm asking you for help in finding right solution. What I want is to stop emitting new particles but all already emitted ones should stay and disappear in the same way as they were while rocket was moving.

Comment: That is incredibly weird. Maybe make sure that `Stop` uses the `StopEmitting` option?

Comment: @LouisGarczynski that didn't helped. Of course when I set `ParticleSystemStopBehavior` to `StopEmittingAndClear`, then smoke trail disappears, but we all know this is not the solution. Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you simply don't call stop ?

Comment: @LouisGarczynski the same as with `Stop()`

Comment: And if you do not destroy the object?

Comment: @LouisGarczynski no difference.

Comment: So the problem is not with the destruction of the emitter, you're simply seeing its normal lifetime. Just put back the destruction functions and increase the particle system start lifetime

Comment: @LouisGarczynski I've changed start lifetime to approx 3. The only difference now is the length of the smoke trail, which is very long.

Comment: Have you tried simply deleting the particle system and starting from scratch?

Comment: @LouisGarczynski I'll have to. Will let you know once I'm done with new attempt.

Comment: Ok, I've got it working as expected. I've set start speed to 0, simulation space to `World` and changed `Rate over Time` into `Rate over Distance` in emission tab. Thanks for your help ;).

Comment: No problem, glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem; after I set the emissionRate of my particle system to zero, all remaining particles would just disappear after about 5 seconds, independent from start lifetime.
Solution for me was to set **Render Alignment** from *View* to *Facing* in the Renderer section of the particle system.